# Different expressions for the guidance equation - how to show equivalence?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bohmian-mechanics

I assume it's not too difficult but I don't know how to show the equivalence between two different expressions of the guidance equation in Bohmian mechanics. The following is the form I already encountered quite often:

$$\dot{\textbf{x}}(t) = \frac{\hbar}{2im|\psi|^2}(\psi^*\nabla\psi - \psi\nabla\psi^*)$$

I recently read "[de Broglie-Bohm, delayed-choice double-slit experiment and density matrix](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229754122_de_Broglie-Bohm_Delayed-Choice_Double-Slit_Experiment_and_Density_Matrix)" by John Bell where he illustrates shortly the basics of Bohmian Mechanics and mentions that "the particle rides along on the wave at some position $\textbf{x}(t)$ with velocity:

$$\dot{\textbf{x}}(t) = \frac{1}{m} \frac{\partial}{\partial\textbf{r}} \text{Im} \log\psi(t,\textbf{r})\bigg\rvert_\textbf{r=x}$$

He doesn't call this equation the guidance equation but I think they're supposed to be the same - does anyone know how to show the equivalence of these two? Where does the $\text{Im} \log$ come from?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write out the derivatve in your second expression. Remember that
$$
\partial_x( \ln \psi)= \frac{1}{\psi} \partial_x \psi,
$$
and ${\rm Im} f= (f-f^*)/2i$
and there you are.

Comment: It was indeed easier than expected - thank you!!